# Securing directory on hosting server

Tags: security

I am writing some php scripts that I am using for personal reasons. One thing I noticed that if I type in the directory on the browser I am able to see all files in the directory.

How can I prevent the browser from viewing any of the files in a directory? I want to be able to send requests to the server and let the server run the script. Can someone point me in the right direction? Should I configure the .htaccess file? If so, what should I be looking for?

FYI: I am on a shared hosted server.

Answer (score 0):

the fast way to do that creat .htaccess ex: under /public_html/

and put this code inside it

```
Options -Indexes
```

all about .htaccess to [more information](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html)

Comment: and server root can use WHM for do that http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/website-troubleshooting/disable-directory-indexes-server-wide

Comment: I created a .htaccess file and put it in my 'www' directory. This is what in my .htaccess file:
Options All -Indexes

Comment: I should of added that I can still access the directory

Comment: other way by your server root
First of all find where is the main apache’s config file httpd.conf is located. If you use Debian, it should be here: /etc/apache/httpd.conf. Using some file editor like Vim or Nano open this file and find the line that looks as follows:

Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

then remove word Indexes and save the file. The line should look like this one:

Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

After it is done, restart apache (e.g. /etc/init.d/apache restart in Debian).